# Передача объекта в из обработчика в обработчик C#

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте. Возник такой вопрос. Есть 2 кнопки, и соответственно два обработчика А и Б. В первом открываем файл и создаем по нему объект. Как передать этот объект во второй обработчик без использования глобальных переменных?

Comment: А чем вас поле класса не устраивает? Оно не глобальная переменная.

Comment: (Но вообще-то, в обработчике нажатия на кнопку читать файлы и создавать объекты не стоит, воспользуйтесь лучше MVVM и делайте модельные вещи на уровне модели, а не представления.)